# How can I put a div over an image?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to put a div over an image so that it acts like a caption, directly ontop of the image.

Sometimes the caption is longer than other times so I can't set a specific margin-top:-px because sometimes the height of the caption is longer.

I tried this and the background of the link (black) does not show, also like I just stated, the caption height changes so this method is garbage:

```
 <div>  

  <img src = "<? echo $image_url ?>" style="float:left;min-width:220px;max-width:220px;">
   <a href="LINK" ><div style="width:210px;background-color:black;color:white;bottom:0;margin-top:-20px;padding-left:10px;padding-top:10px;font-size:16px;"><? echo $title ?></div></a>

 </div>
```

Comment: Why don't you just use `background-image`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<div style="position:relative;">  

  <img src = "<? echo $image_url ?>" style="min-width:220px;max-width:220px;">
   <div style="position:absolute;width:210px;background-color:black;color:white;top:0;left:0;padding-left:10px;padding-top:10px;font-size:16px;z-index:5;"><a href="LINK" ><? echo $title ?></a></div>

</div>
```

You had a few things going on:
1)  You had a div inside an 'a' tag.  You shouldn't put block level elements (like divs) inside inline level elements (like a's).
2)  Remove the float from the image, set your outer div's position to relative and your inner div's position to absolute, then absolutely position it to the top of the containing div.  From there, add a z-index greater than 0 to the inner div for good measure, to ensure it stays stacked above the image.

Comment: This works great! For the record of other posts, in case another user has the same problem, I just switched top:0 to bottom:0 and it does what I needed! Thanks a lot!

Comment: This mostly worked.  I had to add `display: inline-block` to the outer div though in my case.

Answer (score 3):

Add `position:absolute; left:0px;top:0px;z-index: 2;` to current div, and add `style="position:relative;"` in the parent div

```
<div style="position:relative;">  

  <img src = "<? echo $image_url ?>" style="float:left;min-width:220px;max-width:220px;">

<a href="LINK" ><div style="position:absolute;z-index: 2;left:0px;top:0px;width:210px;background-color:black;color:white;bottom:0;padding-left:10px;padding-top:10px;font-size:16px;"><? echo $title ?></div></a>
```

Comment: This seems to be the right direction, how could I make the link div go to the bottom rather than to the top: I tried bottom:0px; instead of top:0px

Comment: it's depend on the image size, if image's height is grater then div's height the bottom:0px; should works.

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS z-index property to align text above image. The element with higher z index appears on the top.

Answer (score 1):

This code should work for what you're trying to do:

```
<div style="background: transparent url('<? echo $image_url ?>') no-repeat 0 0; padding: 10px 0 10px 10px; width: 200px;"><a href="LINK"><? echo $title ?></a></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="position:relative;">  

<img  style=" border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px; 
              width: auto;
              height: 250px"

       src = "https://images.pexels.com/photos/904276/pexels-photo-904276.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350" 
      >

  <div style="position:absolute;
               width:100%;
               background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
               color:white;
               bottom:0;
               left:0;
               padding-left:15px;
               font-size:17px;
               z-index:5;">
    <h3 style ="color:white">Title</h3>
    <h4 style ="color:white">Sub Title</h4>
    <p> Lorel Ipsum Blah blah </p>
  </div>

</div>
```

**Result:**

[image: Demo]

See the Pen [zJPvOB](https://codepen.io/hiteshsahu/pen/zJPvOB/) by Hitesh  Sahu ([@hiteshsahu](https://codepen.io/hiteshsahu)) on [CodePen](https://codepen.io).