# putting a div over a specific image using php

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have this code which detects the last image in the images in my Wordpress post

I want to alter it to put the div #up-arrow over-top the last image.

html

```
        <?php
        preg_match_all('/(<img [^>]*>)/', get_the_content(), $images);
        for( $i=0; isset($images[1]) && $i < count($images[1]); $i++ ) {
        if ($i == end(array_keys($images[1]))) {
        echo sprintf('<div id="last-img">%s</div>', $images[1][$i]);
        continue;
        }
            echo $images[1][$i];
        }
    ?>
```

css

```
#up-arrow { position: absolute; z-index: 10; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12679895/how-can-i-put-a-div-over-an-image)

You need to wrap html in

```
echo sprintf('<div id="last-img">%s</div>', $images[1][$i]);
```

as described in example.

Comment: I'm a bit confused with your answer, I am looking for how to add the #up-arrow div to my code

Comment: try echo sprintf('<div id="last-img"><div class="up_arrow">%s</div></div>', $images[1][$i]); And replace #up_arrow with .up_arrow in the css.